# Search string in database with django. icontains and iexact lookups not fulfill my requirements

Tags: python, django

I have products database in Django. A Product name Eg-(ABCD-E34F). If user searches 'abcd34', how will I get the object of ABCD-E34F product.

Comment: If you're searching for something you've got to search for something similar. `icontains` would be fine there if they just searched for 'abcd' if they want to add the extra, I'd call that user error because it's no longer similar to what they want.

Comment: You either constrain the user to search as expected, or you take a guess at what the user might mean from their input and construct your own method of filtering...

Comment: Then you have to write your own custom searching algorithm. Exactly as @JonClements suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people suggest, this will take some thought on your part to build something that fits your needs. I'd recommend using fuzzy matching which can provide a similarity score against whatever you compare with.

There's a python package that shows some pretty good examples & might fit your requirements; https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy

```
>>> choices = ["Atlanta Falcons", "New York Jets", "New York Giants", "Dallas Cowboys"]
>>> process.extract("new york jets", choices, limit=2)
[('New York Jets', 100), ('New York Giants', 78)]
>>> process.extractOne("cowboys", choices)
("Dallas Cowboys", 90)

>>> process.extractOne("System of a down - Hypnotize - Heroin", songs)
('/music/library/good/System of a Down/2005 - Hypnotize/01 - Attack.mp3', 86)
>>> process.extractOne("System of a down - Hypnotize - Heroin", songs, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
("/music/library/good/System of a Down/2005 - Hypnotize/10 - She's Like Heroin.mp3", 61)
```

Comment: Just to note - this moves everything from the DB level and into the app level though... so most likely won't scale... The OP will probably want to apply some level of filtering to reduce the choices the app retrieves from the DB first... (at which point - they may find a suitable solution anyway...)

Comment: Yeah, but there's no way to fuzzy match with the ORM right? If `icontains` doesn't cut it, you've got to accept performance issues.

Comment: Not ORM native - but depending on the DB backend - it may have a FT index on it which could use a custom extractor... or even my first thought in the OPs example was to split it into two blocks where the length exceeds 4 and then try `model.objects.filter(name__icontains=first_half).filter(name__icontains=second_half)` or something... But who the heck knows without knowing what's reasonable input and what options are available/practical backend wise...